# Help with clean install

Tags: macos, install

I'm now having major problems with my iMac. I had a massive software failure running Mavericks, it damamged the OS and I lost the recovery partition, I then wiped the hard drive clean and tried to upgrade to Yosemite, it failed numerous times (unable to verify etc etc)

I then tried to create bootable Yosemite...also failed with installing one of the essential packages.

I am now running the iMac off a cloned version of my damaged Mavericks OS and the recovery partition says it's Yosemite and doesnt work.

I have also tried to reinstall from Lion CD, again not working.

Also the Internet Recovery does not work.

I seem to be in a loop of trouble....how do I go about just doing a clean install of anything?

Comment: First thing I'd do is Repair the drive itself, from Recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin if none of the (internet-)recovery partitions work it's hard to repair from recovery.. ;-)

Comment: there's a Lion installer to work from, or Internet Recovery… though there's a lot of 'doesn't work' with no proper detail which makes it all guesswork other than the drive might be damaged.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a hardware problem?

Comment: In order to help you, we need you to work with us. Posting a question then walking away would not produce results :) Did you try any of the instructions http://macs.about.com/od/OS-X-Yosemite/ss/Perform-a-Clean-Install-of-OS-X-Yosemite-on-Your-Macs-Startup-Drive.htm and http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/18/clean-install-os-x-yosemite/

Comment: Hi all thanks for your comments,recovery drive thinks it's Yosemite and doesn't work, Internet recovery has error msg 6002f,cd installer hangs saying it needs 23.1 installer and finally I repapired hard drive with DU it says it's ok